# Slight lag spawning new thread causes race condition

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking

I have some initialization code that runs in a new thread, and takes 4-5 seconds to run:

```
public virtual void Initialize()
{
   Adapter.Initialize(this);

   new Thread(delegate()
   {
      using (InitLock.WriteLock()) // <-- InitLock is a ReaderWriterLockSlim
      {
         ingParser = new IngredientParser();
         var ingredientIndex = Adapter.LoadIngredientsForIndex();
         ingParser.CreateIndex(ingredientIndex);

         modeler = new ModelerProxy(this);
         modeler.LoadSnapshot();

         parser = new Parser();
         LoadTemplates();
      }
   }).Start();
}
```

I also have several methods that utilize objects that are initialized in that thread, however they use the same `ReaderWriterLockSlim` object so they'll block if the required objects aren't initialized yet:

```
public virtual Parser Parser
{
   get
   {
      using (InitLock.ReadLock())
      {
         return parser;
      }
   }
}
```

Now, if I run this code:

```
context.Initialize(); // Calls Initialize method above

// Do some other stuff that takes a bit of time

context.Parser.Parse("blah blah");
```

Then, everything works.  However, if I run *this* code:

```
context.Initialize(); // Calls Initialize method above
context.Parser.Parse("blah blah"); // Immediately call Parser
```

Then I get an null reference exception on `parser`.  In other words, my initialization code hasn't been run yet, *and* the `WriteLock` hasn't been established so it won't block the thread.

I've traced this down to the fact there's an ever so slight non-blocking lag when creating a new thread in .NET.  If I add this code:

```
   }
}).Start();

Thread.Sleep(500); // Provides time for initialize thread to start and acquire InitLock
```

And sleep for half a second, everything works great.

**My Question:** I think the `Sleep` call is hacky, and prone to different behavior on different systems.  Is there a better design to wait until the lock is acquired on the new thread before leaving the main thread?  I could acquire the write lock in the first thread and dispose of it in the second thread, but that seems even *more* hacky!

Comment: you could make Initialize block until the thread has completed its work.

Comment: @jdigital - Doesn't that defeat the entire purpose of using a separate thread?